# xcode/android wrapper for a web version

Tags: android, ios, xcode, media-queries

I have a existing website that adapts to different devices through css media queries.

Tablet and mobile users get a targeted version with mobile look and feel.

Would it be possible to wrap this website in a simple xcode/android to call my web application?

It would not be just a call to the web version but handling cache and checking connectivity whenever a page is requested as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, both of them have webviews where you can load the website.
But it might be difficult to get apple's approval

Comment: Thanks, but can you check connectivity before any http request is made from the web app? Also, can you store cached versions of the web app pages?